# Why am I getting TypeError 'list' object is not callable when using map function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am trying to separate some comma-separated numbers given as input:

```
numbers_ = input("Please enter numbers: ")
iterator_ = map(str.split(','), numbers_)
print (next(iterator_))
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Please enter numbers: 1,2,3,4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tomerk\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    print (next(iterator_))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

What am I doing wrong? String is an iterable object. I enter characters separated by commas without spaces.

Comment: print (iterator_)
<map object at 0x000001EDB89D8400>

Comment: if you just need a list iterator, use `iter(numbers_.split(','))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass reference to function in [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map). For your use case, you can use a [*lambda expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) as:

```
numbers = '1,2,3,4'
iterator_ = map(lambda x: x.split(','), numbers)
print(next(iterator_))
# print: ['1']
```

Another example with external function:

```
def get_number(s):
    return s.split(',')

iterator_ = map(get_number, numbers)
```

---

However if you want to get numbers from the string, then you do not need `map` here. You need to directly use `str.split()` as:

```
>>> numbers = '1,2,3,4'
>>> numbers.split(',')
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Additionally if you want to type-cast each number from `str` to `int` type, then you can use `map` as:

```
>>> list(map(int, numbers.split(',')))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

As the syntax is map(fun,itr). The Type Error rises in your code is for str.split(','), not for string. As str.split() returns a list which can't be used as function in map().
Instead of str.split(), you can use lambda function but carefully.
You can use this code :-

```
numbers = input("Please enter numbers: ")
#Tt creates a list of comma seperated elements of type str
temp=numbers.split(',')
iterator_ = map(int, temp)
print(next(iterator_))
```